# How to set up Logitech Z506 5.1 surround system with basic motherboard?

Tags: windows, surround-sound

I have just bought a Logitech Z506 5.1 surround system for my PC. I only have basic 3 ports on the motherboard.

How can I set up surround sound without purchasing sound card.

Comment: What do you consider to be the "basic 3 ports"? If you have stereo mini-jacks with green, black & orange surrounds, they will do 5.1 with appropriate cables. Use these ports on the rear of the sub - https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPSXi.jpg - it's as simple as colour-matching. If you don't, you will need a USB break-out box, from as little as $£€5 on eBay etc. Search "USB 5.1"

Comment: I dont have black and orange. I read you can do something with realtek software. But i cant seem to find a link to download. It only has ethernet drivers

Comment: You can't do anything if you don't have the physical output sockets. You will need a breakout box. Look for one with those 3 colours on the sockets, it will make life considerably simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have stereo mini-jacks with green, black & orange surrounds, they will do 5.1 with appropriate cables. 
Use these ports on the rear of the sub -

[image]

… it's as simple as colour-matching.

The Z506 has no other input options, only 6-channel analog; so you can change plug type, RCA to mini-jack etc, but you cannot use USB or S/PDIF *directly*, you need a 'translator'.
Basically, you need those 3 colours to keep life simplest.

If you don't have those sockets available on your motherboard, you will need a USB break-out box, from as little as $£€5 on eBay etc.
Search "USB 5.1" & avoid the very cheapest which only have 2 socket outputs. They won't do what you expect.

This type -

[image]

not this type -

[image]

Comment: Will quality differ depending in what i buy?

Comment: Not noticeably when your final output is something as basic as a home surround system. Don't let it concern you. The underlying structure for this type of consumer output is so well-established, it really is all the same. That's why it's so cheap these days. You won't gain appreciable quality without spending many hundreds if not thousands of $£€ - far more than the cost of the speakers… & computer ;)

Comment: i spoke to cyberpower to return the product but they said the other 2 ports double up ? so i can use pink and blue